# Templated return type based on paramter type

Tags: c++, c++14

The following function is to return the signed version of its parameter. How would I do that with just one template parameter?

```cpp
template<class UINT_TYPE>
INT_TYPE function_x(const UINT_TYPE n) 
{
  static_assert(std::is_same<UINT_TYPE, uint32_t>::value || 
                std::is_same<UINT_TYPE, uint64_t>::value, 
                "Wrong type passed.");

  return static_cast<INT_TYPE>(n);
}
```

It is possible to use two template parameters with a default value but this is not preferred.

```cpp
template<class UINT_TYPE, class INT_TYPE = typename std::make_signed<UINT_TYPE>::type>
```

If there is any way to do this neatly your ideas are appreciated.

Comment: `std::make_signed`?

Comment: I don't see why this is a question. Since you know what the default for `INT_TYPE` would be, why don't you simply replace each occurrence of "`INT_TYPE`" with what it should be ("`typename std::make_signed<UINT_TYPE>::type>`")? That is, after all, what the compiler would do if you left it as a default for a second template parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can deduce the return type:

```
template <class UINT_TYPE>
auto function_x(const UINT_TYPE n) {
    // ...
    return static_cast<std::make_signed_t<UINT_TYPE>>(n);
}
```

Comment: Yes of course the auto return type! Thank for your reply.

Comment: The `static_cast` isn't needed, is it? I mean `return std::make_signed_t<UINT_TYPE>(n);` should be enough.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's a function-style cast, which is discouraged.

Comment: @Brian I see you point. I wonder why I don't get warnings for that. :-/

Comment: @TedLyngmo You can get a warning if the conversion actually performed is a dangerous one (i.e., integer to pointer, or casting away constness). If it just does an integral conversion, there is no reason for the compiler to issue a warning, as the programmer has merely made a stylistic choice that some people disagree with.

Comment: Sure, but I do get warnings for `unsigned a=10; int b(a);` etc. Seems like the same this as I proposed.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Assuming we're still talking about GCC here: GCC considers this to be a situation where the programmer may not have intended for any conversion to occur. Assuming certain flags, they must be warned in case they made a mistake.

Comment: @Brian Ok, got it!